# Laravel- Dompdf Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.3

Here is error when i convert pdf, it's not working since i run my laravel project by "`php artisan serve --port=1000`". But if i run my laravel project with xampp. it's alright. I don't know why?. Give me explaination and repairs . Thank you

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
    Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

Comment: put  **set_time_limit(6000);**  variable in in your controller file.

Comment: How did you put it? i've already done but  still not working .

Comment: I got it. I set it set_time_limit(300). That's better. Thank you

Comment: which laravel package you are using from generate the DOMPDF?

Answer (score 13):

The laravel - dompdf does not work well with `php artisan serve`. You should use **XAMPP** or another **HTTP server** you like.

Answer (score 9):

What I found was referencing to assets via `asset()` helper in the PDF view was throwing timeout exceeded error, I changed it to `public_path()` and it started working fine.

Comment: This is the best way

Answer (score 8):

Increase Your time limit in your controller file.Below variable to increase your time limit.

```
 set_time_limit(300);
```

Comment: yup but it's pretty long to convert.

Comment: It's resolved. But Do you have any ways to convert pdf with the speed is faster than now?.it's really slow.  Thank you very much

Comment: which laravel package you are using from generate the DOMPDF?

Comment: @Thanh Toàn yes, it's the good package. I think a problem with your data limits.

Comment: @Thanh Toàn Thanks for the thank you. Feel free to accept this as answer and upvote if our solution addressed your concern.

Answer (score 3):

For me, there were two main issues.

1. **Using images directly:** I was using images with `storage_path()` so, I first convert image to base64 and pass it to the blade view.
2. **Using external CSS:** I was using bootstrap as external CSS and as we don't need whole bootstrap CSS, I just copy required CSS from bootstrap and place in internally with `<style>..</style>`

These steps make the PDF generation process very fast.

Answer (score 3):

use **public_path** for your external files for exe  `href="{{public_path('style.css')}}"`

Comment: In your pdf blade page, replace asset by public_path

Answer (score 2):

dompdf does not work on
`php artisan server`

You should go through xampp server.
It solved my problem

Comment: this is worked in my windows thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and narrowed it down to linking to an image in my blade file. When I embedded the image instead as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952877/adding-an-image-with-dompdf), it no longer timed out.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible causes:**

***linking to external CSS*** - you're better off writing your css between style tags in the same file as your html

***using blade templating syntax*** e.g. @sections @roles, etc

***linking to external images***

***Complex table structures/layouts***

...from personal experience

Comment: Linking to external CSS is actually best practice, as you only need to change a given class in one place, not in all pages.