# How to print an image with DomPDF in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

I am making a pdf, for which I use the library: **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf**, in the pdf I try to print an image, with which when I open the recently downloaded file, all the data is printed except the image, **I clarify this image if it is displayed correctly in my show.blade view**, I cannot find a solution for this problem.
Below I detail how I am proceeding:

Controller: (fragment of store method and exportPdf method)

```
    public function store(SaveDocumentRequest $request)
    {
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {               

        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);   
    }else{
          $name = null; 
    }  
   $document->photo  = $name;
```

```
    public function exportPdf()
    {
        $movie = Movies::with('document.creator', 'actors', 'generate_movie', 'document.adequacy', 'document.lenguage')->first();

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.movies.show', compact('movie'));  
       
        return $pdf->download('cine.pdf');
    }
```

My show.blade file:

```
<div class="col-md-6">    
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Imagen de Portada </h3>
            </div>        
            <div class="box-body box-profile">                                          
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}"  alt="{{ $movie->document->title }}" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This way I am accessing the image that if it is displayed correctly in my show.blade file, but it is not displayed in the downloaded pdf.**

**I clarify I do not receive any type of error and the image is stored in the public folder of the project.**

Could you guide me to find the solution?

Comment: Try with public_path() `{{ public_path('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}` or with base_path() `{{ base_path('/images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}`

Comment: as told by @sta you can try changing the path, if it does not work then try this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952877/adding-an-image-with-dompdf/37953303

Answer (score 0):

Its simple just use this I have used same package and added image on pdf like this.

```
 <img  src="{{asset('foldername/path_to_image')}}">
```

Comment: my project is on localhost it is locally. Has the solution you are giving me been implemented in localhost?

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late it's working fine on both environment

Comment: just that I am doing ```<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('images/'.$movie->document->photo) }}"  alt="{{ $movie->document->title }}" >``` for some reason it is not working for me

Comment: could you pls print this path ` dd('images/'.$movie->document->photo) ` and confirm if image exist, I think you have empty object or after printing path confirm if the image is already there.

Comment: Remember that the image can be seen in the browser, but when the pdf is downloaded, all the data is displayed except the image Inspecting with ```dd('images/'.$movie->document->photo)```
The result is as follows: ```"images/1597609005piano_concertos.jpeg"```, that's the image path

Comment: Can you see my store method? if it is how I store the image

Comment: ```public function store(SaveDocumentRequest $request)
    {
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {               

        $file = $request->file('photo');
        $name = time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);   
    }else{
          $name = null; 
    }  
   $document->photo  = $name;``` please check my original post there is my store method

Comment: ?Can I check on yours pc

Comment: sure! leave id pls

Comment: this my anydesk  430 774 813

Comment: let know when you get online!

Comment: hace  I leave my email rjruizsf@gmail.com please I need your help let me know when I am online